# Is there a way to make `viw` to select the current word that contains `-`?

Tags: vimrc

As title says, I try to select the whole word with `viw` but if the naming convention is aaa-b-ccc, then I can't do that with this command. I have tried `viW` but this will include other symbols too which is not what I want.

Is there a way to only include `-` for w?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: @filbranden Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can control that with the `'iskeyword'` option. To include dashes, you can use this command:

```
set iskeyword+=-
```

You'll probably want to use `setlocal` and limit that to the specific filetype where you want dashes to be recognized as identifiers.

You can create a file `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/<your-filetype>.vim` with that `setlocal` command to ensure `-` is always included in words when editing files of that specific type.

See also [`:help word`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#word):

> A word consists of a sequence of letters, digits and underscores, or a sequence of other non-blank characters, separated with white space (spaces, tabs, `<EOL>`).  This can be changed with the `'iskeyword'` option.  An empty line is also considered to be a word.

Comment: Just tried this out and work perfectly! Thanks a lot for this great answer! :)

Comment: @TonyLin Glad it worked for you!

Comment: @TonyLin just remember this affects all word motions (which you probably wanted)!